# yii2 ActiveForm without begin form tag

Tags: forms, yii2

I need to generate widgets\ActiveForm::field() without "form" tag at begin. I looked in source of yii\widgets\ActiveForm and found that this can not be avoided :(

```
public function init()
{
    if (!isset($this->options['id'])) {
        $this->options['id'] = $this->getId();
    }
    echo Html::beginForm($this->action, $this->method, $this->options);
}
```

Maybe there's another way to solve this problem without extending the 'ActiveForm' class?

Answer (score 1):

*ActiveField* is basically just a wrapper for *yii\helpers\Html::active...* methods so you just can call `echo yii\helpers\Html::activeTextInput($model, $attribute, $options);` without using *ActiveForm*

Comment: thx, I tried but `Html::activeTextInput()` not support `Html::activeTextInput()->widget()` construction :(

Comment: is something wrong with this approach ? you've got an error ?

Comment: if you want to call widget, you can call it directly by `echo YourWidget::widget($config)` where `$config` is a widget confriguration array